# Issue in the alignment of Divs

Tags: html, css

I have three Div .Two of which i have aligned as two cells of table row and third one i want to display down .But this third Div is getting displayed after the Second Div gets ended Which i dont want .I want third Div i.e with id `menu` to get displayed after the button `frontdesk`.Here is the css used..

```
#wrapper {
display:table;
position:relative;
height:auto;
width: 100%;
}
#row {
display:table-row;
}
#first {
display:table-cell;
width:75%;
}
#second {
display:table-cell;
width:25%;
height:600px;
}
.menucss {
position:relative;
display:table-row;
width: 168px;
height:auto;
}
```

and here is the fiddle link..
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kzg5wy3/).Please help me to correct this..Thanks..

Comment: Could you show a diagram of how you expect it to be laid out?

Comment: If you want 'second' to appear below 'first', don't put it in the table row?

Comment: @Askanison4 Please see my fiddle.In the fiddle please scroll down .At last you will see one lable `Menu List` .I want this lable to be at top just below the frontdesk button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try position:absolute with your .menucss class i.e:

```
.menucss
{
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 width: 168px;
 height:auto;    
}
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7kzg5wy3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```css
#wrapper {
display:table;
position:relative;
height:auto;
width:  100%;
}
#row {
    display:table-row;
}
#first {
    display:table-cell;
    width:75%;
}
#second {
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
    height:600px;
}


.menucss
{
 position:absolute;
 top:25px;
 height:auto;    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="first">
            <button id="Front Desk" style="margin-left:15px;vertical-align:top; font-size:20px;">Front Desk</button>
            <button id="Report" style="margin-left:15px; vertical-align:top; font-size:20px;">Report</button>
        </div>
        <div id="second" style="border:1px solid;">This is the Sample Computation Div...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="menucss">
        <br />
        <label id="menulist" style="font-style:normal;margin-left:25px; font-size:15px;font-weight:bold; float:left; padding-left:0px;">Menu List</label>
      
    </div>
</div>
```